# how to add a line or hr tag between dynamic created <ul> and <li> after a number of <li>

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, count

i'm working in wordpress with twitter bootstrap theme. i just made a template which fetch the values from repeater fields like image, name, designation etc and i call these values in my template in ul and li now i want that after 4 li there will be a hr tag or line how can i achieve it.

Here is my code for getting the data from repeater field into my template:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<?php $gcount=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'europe_speaker', true);
            for($i=0;$i<$gcount;$i++){ 
            $photo=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_photo", true);
            $name=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_name", true);
            $designation=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_designation", true);
            $company=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_company", true);
            $line=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_line", true);
            $category=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_category", true);
            $download=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_download", true);
            $download_link=get_post_meta($post->ID, "europe_speaker_".$i."_download_link", true);

            ?>

<li class="span2">
<div class="speakers_img-height">
<img src="<?php echo $photo?>" class="img-polaroid" style="margin-bottom:5px;"/><br/><span style="color:#686868;"><strong><?php echo $name?></strong><br/><?php echo $designation?><br/><?php echo $company; ?><br/><a href="<?php echo $download_link; ?>"><?php echo $download; ?></a></span>
</div>
</li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
```

after giving li span2 class it will give 4 li in a row and i want to add a line or hr tag after that.please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery code...

```
jQuery("ul li:nth-child(4)").append("<hr class='whatever' />");
```

For every forth element try...

```
jQuery("ul li:nth-child(4n+0)").append("<hr class='whatever' />");
```

Comment: @ManindraSingh you have to use your class in the selector jQuery(ul.thumbnails li:nth-child(4))

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: Just check the value of `i`:

```
for($i=0;$i<$gcount;$i++){ 
   if (i == 3){ echo "<hr />"; }
...
```

Note that you check "3" and not "4" because "`i`" starts at 0

Comment: yupp i have also done that but adding this code where li closed it shows the line after the 4th li in same row not after that li means not in next line.

Comment: @ Sylverdrag: is ther any other solution or i m writing the code at wrong place. coz this code shows the line side by side the 4th li and i want like 4 li the a hr tag in nxt line the again 4 li

Answer (score 0):

Add this after `</li>`

```
if($i==NUMBER_YOU_WANT)
{
   echo"<li><hr></li>";
}
```

Note:You can put any class you want at `<li>`

Comment: @ Moataz Mohamed: its not working page just showing the hr tag but line is not visible.

Comment: @ Moataz Mohamed: i try your code but as i give the value of $i = something then the loop will rotate only once and then the line will print just once not second time

Comment: @Manindra Singh tell me please Do you want to make hr after every li?

Comment: or after every fixed number like "every 4 li"